# How to run pure-ftpd with port range as a service

Tags: debian, parameter, pure-ftpd

I am running pure-ftpd on raspbian, I need to pass it parameters to specify the port range for data connections, I read the following page here

[pure-ftpd faq](https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ)

it mentions that I can run the process directly like below..

```
Example: /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd -p 50000:50400
```

I believe the way to start and stop the services is as below

```
 sudo service pure-ftpd start
```

How can I pass it parameters  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it, it was not straight forward but after a analyzing the script that runs that service of pure-ftpd, i figure that the script

```
  /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd
```

starts another script called

```
 pure-ftpd-wrapper
```

Looking at this script it apprears to read some configuration values from disk, then searching for manpage of pure-ftpd-wrapper took me to page
[pure-ftpd-wrapper manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/pure-ftpd-wrapper.8.html)
Here we can see that configs are palace in directory

```
  /etc/pure-ftpd/conf
```

Here in this directory there is one file for each parameter of the executable
So all I had to do was create a file by the name of

```
  PassivePortRange
```

In the conf directory and then put my port numbers seperated by space in there

```
  echo "50000 50100" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange
```

After this change service must be restarted for the changes to take effect

```
  sudo service pure-ftpd restart
```

Done! Now you can access your ftp service even if it is behind a NAT/Firewall assuming you have done port forwarding for port 21 and the above range of ips and use passive mode in the ftp client.